# How to remove the class from all elements except the clicked element?

Tags: javascript

When the user clicks on the paragraph, if there is any paragraph with the class selected, remove it from all the paragraphs except the paragraph he clicked on.

```js
var
    paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0],
    paragraphChildrens = paragraph.children,
    y = 0;
 
for (; y < paragraphChildrens.length; y++) {
    const _children = paragraphChildrens[y];

    _children.onclick = () => {
        _children.classList.add("selected");  
    }
}
```

```css
p{
height: 30px;
background: red
}
p.selected{
height: 100px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Services</p>
  <p>About Us</p>
  <p>Contacts</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walking through the list of children is expensive.
Handling events on each child is expensive too.

So:

1. Delegate event handling to the parent.
2. Remember previously selected element and handle it before assing the class to the new element.

```js
let selectedP;

document.querySelector('div').onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName != 'P') return;
  select(e.target);
};

function select(p) {

  if (selectedP) {
selectedP.classList.remove('selected');
  }

  selectedP = p;
  selectedP.classList.add('selected');

}
```

```css
p{
height: 30px;
background: red
}
p.selected{
height: 100px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Services</p>
  <p>About Us</p>
  <p>Contacts</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly simple.  In your function call, remove the class "selected" from every element before adding it to the element you need.

```js
var
    paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0],
    paragraphChildrens = paragraph.children,
    y = 0;
 
for (; y < paragraphChildrens.length; y++) {
    const _children = paragraphChildrens[y];
    
    _children.onclick = () => {
        //new code start
        var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p")
        paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => {
            paragraph.classList.remove("selected")
        })

        _children.classList.add("selected");  
    }
}
```

```css
p{
height: 30px;
background: red
}
p.selected{
height: 100px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Services</p>
  <p>About Us</p>
  <p>Contacts</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const pElemnts = document.querySelectorAll('p')
  pElemnts.forEach(pEl => {
    pEl.onclick = clickP
  })

  function clickP (evt) {
    pElemnts.forEach(pEl => {
      pEl.classList.remove('selected')
    })
    evt.target.classList.add('selected')
  }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.